# convert unique string to unique number and vice versa

Tags: string, algorithm, casting, unique

I generate unique strings as IDs based on different parameters. I need to have this kind of IDs because the string must be understandable for users. However I want to save these IDs in database as numbers

How can I convert unique strings to unique numbers and vice versa?

Comment: That rather depends on the specifics of your “unique strings”. A very basic approach would be to assign a number to each possible character (and fill those numbers up to the same length.) `A`=`01`, `B`=`02`, etc. - “converting” from and to `ABBA` resp. `01020201` would be rather trivial then. Of course more sophisticated approaches are possible. (Careful though with your specification – `01020201` would not be an actual _number_. It really depends on what exactly you need, but you kept it very vague.)

Comment: Thanks, if you have a string with 50 characters, the number will be 100 digits, which is a little bit too long.

Comment: See, that’s what was meant by “depends on the specifics” … (plus, it might be even _more_, if the range of possible characters to chose from was greater than 100 – because then you’d need more than two digits to be able to uniquely identify each character.) As I said, this is a very basic approach. But more than this can hardly be provided unless you come up with a proper definition of the requirements in the first place.

Comment: How long do you want those unique strings to be? What characters do you want those strings to contain? For example, do you want them to contain upper case ASCII letters A through Z, plus the digits 0 through 9? How many different unique IDs do you want to generate? There are many ways to do what you're asking, but they depend on what kind of strings you want to generate.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a parser (from int to char and vice versa) and lots of programming languages have that function included.

Comment: will all numbers be unique? what about these two strings "good" and "doog"?